# Find all table rows with class x and is visible within a fieldset and checkbox them

Tags: jquery

My apologies for lack of better title..

I am successfully using the following line:

```
$('.checkall').unbind('click').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

When .checkall is clicked all table rows within the fieldset will be checked. Now I use a pagination within my table which sets the rows that are not on the frontpage to class 'canView display:none';

How can I filter for every checkbox within the fieldset with the class canView but without the display:none;

i.e.:

```
$(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('tr > canView:VISIBLE').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
```

But this does not work they way I think it should :)

**note**: Every tr has the class canView, only display is changed when paginated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code is this:

```
$(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('tr > canView:VISIBLE').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
```

The issue is with the selector in the `.find('tr > canView:VISIBLE')` part.

`'tr > canView:VISIBLE'` would look for all visible elements of the `<canView>` tag that are immediate descendents of a `<tr>` element. You want `<tr>` elements with the class `canView` that are visible, so you need this:

```
.find('tr.canView:visible')
```

Comment: Ah! I was so close :) Thank you very much! Works perfect.